# Vue js 2.0 display large data in table

Tags: php, vue.js

for small size data vue working fine.but when i am loading large data like 5k then taking long time.and in browser it showing out of memory. what is the best way to display large data

Comment: i am using DataTable to show data . here is how i am showing in html 
<tr v-for="user in rs">
                                        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                                        <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
                                        <td>{{user.lastname}}</td>
                                        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                                        <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
                                    </tr>

Comment: Don't post code in the comments, hard to read/understand. Instead, please [edit] your question and paste all relevant information there. Thanks

Comment: Use pagination/chunking for your data. (Not a great UX to scroll through/view 5k of data)

Answer (score 0):

Either use some pagination with a limited amount of elements in your table or [this package](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller).
This can use some tricks to optimize the whole thing DOM-wise and avoid the heavy computation via the CPU of a fast scroll on all of them.

Still, pagination is better on a lot of aspects. Or some other solution with a nice UX (maybe a search field).

Answer (score -1):

ok vuetifyjs solved. i am using this for large data and working fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).